# FeathersJS + Auth0: Authenticated but user not populated

Tags: authentication, auth0, feathersjs

I installed the Auth0 lock and can login on my client side, with an `idToken` in my localStorage.

I send this `idToken` to my API server - a FeathersJS server, which is basically an extension to an Express server. I get authenticated correctly using JWT, but the user is empty in my `req` object (it's called student here):

```
{ authenticated: true,
  query: {},
  provider: 'rest',
  headers: { (truncated...) },
  student: {},
  payload: 
   { iss: 'https://mydomain.eu.auth0.com/',
     sub: 'myusername',
     aud: 'myaudience',
     exp: 1494125072,
     iat: 1494089072 } }
```

The 5 last lines are the payload contained inside Auth0's `idToken`.

The fact that my `student` user object is empty is kind of normal when I think about it, because the app doesn't know how to link a Auth0 user to one of my database users. It's done by the username property. But how do I tell my Feathers app that? Is there a `populateUser` or something similar?

I remembered such a function in the old Feathers, but the new one uses the common hook's `populate` function: see [here](https://github.com/feathersjs/feathers-authentication/blob/master/docs/migrating.md):

> `populateUser` -> use new `populate` hook in feathers-hooks-common

So I tried this new `populate` hook, but unfortunately it's only an After hook, which doesn't make sense since I want to populate the user before making the request.

And now I'm stuck. I mean, I could write my own before hook which populates the user, but I bet there's some nicer way to achieve what I want.

Below is some relevant code:

*authentication.js*

```
const authentication = require('feathers-authentication');
const jwt = require('feathers-authentication-jwt');
const oauth2 = require('feathers-authentication-oauth2');
const Auth0Strategy = require('passport-auth0').Strategy;

module.exports = function () {
  const app = this;
  const config = app.get('authentication');

  // Set up authentication with the secret
  app.configure(authentication(config));
  app.configure(jwt());
  app.configure(oauth2({
    name: 'auth0',
    Strategy: Auth0Strategy,
  }));


  // The `authentication` service is used to create a JWT.
  // The before `create` hook registers strategies that can be used
  // to create a new valid JWT (e.g. local or oauth2)
  app.service('authentication').hooks({
    before: {
      create: [
        authentication.hooks.authenticate(config.strategies)
      ],
      remove: [
        authentication.hooks.authenticate('jwt')
      ]
    }
  });
};
```

*config file*

```
{
  ...
  "authentication": {
    "entity": "student",
    "service": "students",
    "secret": "SAME_SECRET_AS_BELOW",
    "strategies": [
      "jwt"
    ],
    "path": "/authentication",
    "jwt": {
      "header": {
        "type": "access"
      },
      "audience": "SAME_AUDIENCE_AS_BELOW",
      "subject": "anonymous",
      "issuer": "https://mydomain.eu.auth0.com/",
      "algorithm": "HS256",
      "expiresIn": "1d"
    },
    "auth0": {
      "clientID": "SAME_AUDIENCE_AS_ABOVE",
      "clientSecret": "SAME_SECRET_AS_ABOVE",
      "domain": "https://mydomain.eu.auth0.com/"
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: how about changing the default options, [feathers-authentication](https://github.com/feathersjs/feathers-authentication#default-options) you can change the entity and service. I think it does add the user automatically after you authenticate... also the current auth still does a get user, so doing you idea of getting the user on before hooks is okay.

Comment: As for why populate in hooks common work that way, its [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/43725099/chat-app-tut-purpose-of-populate/43734140#43734140)